# Jquery Datatable: Count records with Left Join and Where clause

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, 'team' and 'tickets'. Right now its displaying all records and also which ticket the team member is dispatched too.

I now need to count the number of tickets for each team.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609d4f/18

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT
    team.techid,
    team.name,
    tickets.techid,
    tickets.customer,
    tickets.callstatus,
    tickets.serialnumber
FROM team
LEFT JOIN tickets
    ON tickets.techid = team.techid AND (tickets.callstatus = 'Dispatch') AND 
(COUNT(tickets.customer) WHERE tickets.techid = team.techid )
```

**Update**

Working example but only missing the count column:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609d4f/19

**Update2**

Tim, thank you for your help but your example doesn't work.

The table should look like this, minus the missing columns of course:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Tech ID        |     Count        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Tech1       |      1           |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Tech2       |      1           |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Tech3       |      0           |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfcdf5/1

As you see below, tech1 and tech2 both have records in ato_openservicecalls where the SC_CallStatus is Dispatch

```
insert into `serviceteam` VALUES (1, 'tech1', 'name1', 'manager1', 'dispatcher1', 'cellphone1');
insert into `serviceteam` VALUES (2, 'tech2', 'name2', 'manager2', 'dispatcher2', 'cellphone2');
insert into `serviceteam` VALUES (3, 'tech3', 'name3', 'manager3', 'dispatcher3', 'cellphone3');


insert into `ato_openservicecalls` VALUES (1, 'tech1', 'Dispatch', 'customer1', 'age1', 'timestamp1', 'serial1', 'comment1');
insert into `ato_openservicecalls` VALUES (2, 'tech2', 'Dispatch', 'customer2', 'age2', 'timestamp2', 'serial2', 'comment2');
insert into `ato_openservicecalls` VALUES (3, 'tech3', 'callstatus3', 'customer3', 'age3', 'timestamp3', 'serial3', 'comment3');



SELECT
t1.techid,
t1.techname,
t1.manager,
t1.dispatcher,
t1.cellphone,
t2.SC_SCTechID,
t2.BCARNA,
t2.SC_CallStatus,
t2.Serial_ID,
t2.Age,
t2.SC_CallTimestamp,
t2.SC_CallComment,
COALESCE(t3.num_tickets, 0) AS num_tickets
FROM serviceteam t1
LEFT JOIN ato_openservicecalls t2
    ON t1.techid = t2.SC_SCTechID AND t2.SC_CallStatus = 'Dispatch'
    LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.techid, COUNT(*) AS num_tickets
    FROM serviceteam t1
    INNER JOIN ato_openservicecalls t2
        ON t1.techid = t2.SC_SCTechID
    WHERE t2.SC_CallStatus = 'Dispatch'
) t3
    ON t1.techid = t3.techid;
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  Do you really want to see separate rows for each separate ticket associate with every team?

Comment: No, what's expected is a column for tech id, name, customer, call status, serial number and count of total number of tickets for that tech id. I have everything except the count.

Comment: Um...you're selecting `ticket` fields.  Maybe you should add your expected output.  The above comment does not agree with your question.

Comment: Hi Tim, did you click on this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/609d4f/19 ? All i need is to add another column to this that will show the total number of tickets for each techid.

Comment: I can't seem to open Fiddle from my computer, but I gave an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL versions earlier than 8+, we can find the counts using a subquery and then join to it:

```
SELECT
    t1.techid,
    t1.name,
    t2.techid,
    t2.customer,
    t2.callstatus,
    t2.serialnumber,
    COALESCE(t3.num_tickets, 0) AS num_tickets
FROM team t1
LEFT JOIN tickets t2
    ON t1.techid = t2.techid AND t2.callstatus = 'Dispatch'
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.techid, COUNT(*) AS num_tickets
    FROM team t1
    INNER JOIN tickets t2
        ON t1.techid = t2.techid
    WHERE t2.callstatus = 'Dispatch'
) t3
    ON t1.techid = t3.techid;
```

With MySQL 8+ or later, we can take advantage of analytic functions:

```
SELECT
    t1.techid,
    t1.name,
    t2.techid,
    t2.customer,
    t2.callstatus,
    t2.serialnumber,
    COUNT(t2.customer) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.techid) num_tickets
FROM team t1
LEFT JOIN tickets t2
    ON t1.techid = t2.techid AND t2.callstatus = 'Dispatch';
```

**Edit:**

You completely changed your question, invalidating my first accepted answer.  Here is the new query:

```
SELECT
    t1.techid,
    COUNT(t2.customer) AS num_tickets
FROM team t1
LEFT JOIN tickets t2
    ON t1.techid = t2.techid AND t2.callstatus = 'Dispatch'
GROUP BY
    t1.techid;
```

Comment: It is rude to change your question like this, you should ask a new question.  In any case, the new query you need is easy, and I have included it above.

Comment: I'm sorry, i will be more clear with my questions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is still not working properly. Your query counts the TOTAL number of records. I need it to display per tech id. Tech 1 - 1 Count, Tech 2: 1 Count, Tech 3: 0 count. Right now it has Tech 1: 2 calls even with your new query.

Comment: Missing a `GROUP BY` clause, sorry.  I am on a cell phone right now.  Hence the importance of asking a clear question the first time around.